# How to do a nested If / and statement in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access

This is easy to do in excel, however, I can't figure out how to do the same thing in Access and need to do it in Access for reasons.

I have a table that determines a commission payout percentage based on the sale amount.  So if a sale is $250 the payout is 0%.  If it's $3500, the payout is 1%.  It's all in one huge table. See below example

> =iif(AND([gross commission]>0,[gross commission]<501),"0%",iif(AND([gross commission ]>500,[gross
> commission ]<1501),"1.25%",iif(AND([gross commission]>1500,[gross
> commission ]<5001),"1%",iif(AND([gross commission ]>5000,[gross
> commission]<10001),".9%",iif(AND([gross commission ]>10000,[gross
> commission ]<20001),".8%",iif(AND([gross commission]>20000,[gross
> commission ]<50001),".7%",iif(AND([gross commission
> ]>50001),".6%","problem"))))))))

I get an invalid syntax error, "you may have entered a comma w/o a preceding value or identifier".  I haven't had a Google search result that deals with this type of nested formula.

Thanks very much in advance for all suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing extraordinary about your requirement.
The IIf() pattern still applies:
`IIf(conditional expression here, do this if true, else do this if false).`
Access syntax for your requirement would be:
`=IIf([gross commission]>0 AND [gross commission]<501, "0%", IIf(... )))))))`

However, the AND compound criteria is not necessary.

Consider:

```
=IIf([gross commission]<501,"0%", 
IIf([gross commission]<1501,"1.25%", 
IIf([gross commission]<5001,"1%", 
IIf([gross commission]<10001,"0.9%", 
IIf([gross commission]<20001,"0.8%", 
IIf([gross commission]<50001,"0.7%", 
IIf([gross commission]>=50001,"0.6%","problem")))))))
```

Or:

```
=Switch([gross commission]<501,"0%", 
[gross commission]<1501,"1.25%", 
[gross commission]<5001,"1%", 
[gross commission]<10001),"0.9%", 
[gross commission]<20001),"0.8%", 
[gross commission]<50001),"0.7%", 
[gross commission]>=50001,"0.6%", 
True, "problem")
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much for the details.  Only issue is that Access doesn't recognize the  ' => ' option so I just changed the last one to be "0.7%","0.6%".

Comment: Access VBA is okay with either => or >= but apparently SQL is pickier. Use >=. Edited answer.

Comment: Actually, VBA will automatically change => to >=. And the immediate window works with both.

Comment: appreciate the followup clarifications!